# Problems forming multiple collections and models in Backbone.js

Tags: json, backbone.js, collections, models

I am having issues creating a multiple collections and models. I am trying to form a basic Backbone.js Collection.

I am having two issues.

1. Looking at the console log of whats passed through to the view I can see the `Event` model is not actually being created (There is no id: 'No ID' in the attributes). I know that the collection Months forms Month models but I cannot explain why Events is not forming Event models.
2. Collections are only formed when the Months collection is initialized with reset:true. I have no idea how to explain this

I have a collection of `Months` of the model `Month`. The model `Month` has a collection of `Events` of the model `Event` as follows:

```
$(function(){
var Event = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        id: 'No ID',
        description: 'No description',
        startdate: 'No startdate'
    }

});

var Events = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Event,

    parse: function(response) {
        return response;
    }
});

var Month = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() {
        return {
            events: new Events(this.get('events'))
        };
    }
});

var Months = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Month,
    url : '/api/v1/calendar/2014',  

    initialize: function(){
        this.fetch({
            reset: true
        });
    },

    parse: function(response) {
        if ('months' in response) {
            console.log('Months Collection: ' + response);
            return response.months;
        } else {
            console.error('No months found.'); 
        }
    }

});

window.Calendar = new Months();
});
```

An example of the JSON I am trying to interpret here:

```
{
"status": "success",
"year": 2014,
"months": [
    {
        "month": 1,
        "events": [
            {
                "title": "None",
                "startdate": "2014-01-23",
                "enddate": "None",
                "description": "description 1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "month": 12,
        "events": [
            {
                "title": "None",
                "startdate": "2014-12-24",
                "enddate": "None",
                "description": "description 2"
            },
            {
                "title": "None",
                "startdate": "2014-12-25",
                "enddate": "None",
                "description": "description 3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the id from the defaults altogether.
The id is a representation of id's that are present in the back end; if the id on a Backbone model is present, then the library assumes that you are working with a model that exists in the back end (and has a corresponding id there).
If the model was not persisted to a data source yet, then the model doesn't have an id and should therefore be empty. Functionally, backbone will in that case perform a `POST` instead of `PUT` on `save()`, when the model does not have an id defined.

`{reset:true}`fires an explicit reset event on the entire collection (instead of the default `set` per model), but this should not be required to fetch the models from the server. 
For getting access to the models that were fetched, you should implement a callback function though, which takes the response of the model's fetch method as parameter. When you call `this.fetch()`, a promise is returned, which you have yet to process.